# RxJava/Retrofit - How can I force users to use a specific subclass of Subscriber?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

Before using `rx.Observable`, I used a custom callback with retrofit so I can add some specific logic for handling response/error and not have to do that inside the callback for every request as boilerplate code.

I force users to use the custom callback by putting it in the method signature like this:

```
@GET("/user_endpoint/")
void getUser(CustomCallback<User> callback);

@GET("/profile_endpoint/")
void getProfile(CustomCallback<Profile> callback);
```

but now that I'm returning an `Observable`:

```
@GET("/user_endpoint/")
Observable<User> getUser();

@GET("/profile_endpoint/")
Observable<Profile> getProfile();
```

I can't figure out a way to make sure that a custom callback always proxies the error/response.

Also, with retrofit2.0, how can I force the user to use a custom callback with the returned `Call` object?

CustomCallback for reference:

```
public abstract class CustomCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

  @Override public final void success(T t, Response response) {
    // do some logic
    onSuccess(t);
  }

  @Override public final void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    // do something with the error here such as show a Toast
    Toast.makeText(Application.getInstance(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    onFailure(error);
  }

  public abstract void onSuccess(T response);

  public abstract void onFailure(Throwable error);
}
```

Comment: The questions is why do you need to return an observable, when obvously you're not able to use just any observable? Why not make CustomCallback extend Observable and then return this as the type? When you say you want to make sure it proxies the response, where do you want to proxy it, to the observers?

Comment: the returned type has to be an rx.Observable, not a subclass https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.4.0/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L244

Answer (score -1):

Stop. You're thinking this the wrong way.

Instead consider this: You have the normal Retrofit interface:

```
interface Foo {
   @GET("/user_endpoint/")
   Observable<User> getUser();
}
```

And then you have your decorator class:

```
public class FooDecorator implements Foo {
    private Foo delegate = ...; // inject or create the Retrofit instance.

    @Override
    public Observable<User> getUser() {
       return delegate.getUser().doOnNext(...).doOnError(...);
    }
}
```

Then you use only the second class everywhere in your code (preferably just let the DI system use that) and you're set.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could even adapt the `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` so that it modifies the returned observables without the need of a custom class.

Comment: I know that creating a decorator class will work but it requires you to implement every method with the same logic. I was looking for a cleaner solution. And `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java is a final class so I'd have to use my own fork of retrofit which is not the solution I was looking for

Comment: If you want, you can use a `java.lang.reflext.Proxy` to do the wrapping, then you don't need an explicit class.